# How to set JFace ListViewer size?

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

OK - I give up.

How can I set width and height of a JFace ListViewer?

This should be self-evident but can't seem to find anything and there's no obvious way of doing it looking at the methods of the class.

Tried this with no luck:

```
myListViewer.getControl().setSize(1000, 1000);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set the size explicitly. you use layouts instead. Layouts manage the size and position of your widgets in a container. Read [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) eclipse article that will help you understand SWT layouts.

Comment: thanks for the link - so there is no way to achieve a fixed layout in swt?

Answer (score 3):

To do this you can set a layoutdata to your List associated with the ListViewer

```
myListViewer.getControl().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
```

to resize the control to fill the cell horizontally and to fit the remaining horizontal space.